# Why is child element not taking 100% height of its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: darkgreen;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid darkgreen;
}

.text {
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.checkbox {
  border-left: 3px solid darkgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 45px;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-2XFplPlrFClt0bIdPgpz8H7ojnk10H69xRqd9+uTShA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Vollkorn:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="text">Some Text Here</div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am unable to understand why the `border-left: 3px solid darkgreen;` on `.checkbox` doesn't take up 100% height of its parent i.e `.header`.

I am adding padding to `.text` and I guess somehow that padding is being applied to `.checkbox` as well.

I am stuck at this for hours now, any help to rectify this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Even if I add `padding: 3px 0;` to `.checkbox`, then the problem is solved for this case, but if the screen size is reduced to a point where the text within `.text` cannot fit in a single line and occupies two lines, the same problem occurs again. So, it looks ugly on mobile devices.
[image]

Comment: because you have padding in `text`.

Comment: @Manjuboyz How can I resolve it, and why adding padding to `.text` affects `.checkbox`?

Comment: @Manjuboyz I want the padding that is why it is there and according to me `text` is not parent to `checkbox`, both are siblings.

Comment: Oops my bad, will check thanks. if I may ask necessity for the padding?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a padding top/bottom of 3px to your .text that affect the height of the parent. Even if your checkbox has a 100% height, it cannot reach the border of the parent due to this padding.
The easiest solution is to add a padding to your .checkbox

```css
.checkbox{
  padding: 3px 0px;
}
```

CHANGE

So do not use padding to do the trick on multiple line, you can use flex
on your header, using 'align-items:stretch' will force the .checkbox to take the whole size of its parent but you need to remove its height too (of the .checkbox)
Then you need to center the 'fa-check', you just have to center it with flex on the checkbox

```css
.header: {
   align-items: stretch;
}

.checkbox{
  display : flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* height: 100%;
     padding: 3px 0px;
  */
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that it works fine in this case, but if the window is resized to a smaller size, the `text` takes two lines and then again there is a problem. How to fix that?

Comment: I have added an update to my question, please have a look!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common scenario. It has led to a lot of confusion. But it doesn't take up all the screen because the parent elements don't take up 100% of the height. So the solution would be to set the height of all parent nodes to 100%. Even `html`!

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: darkgreen;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid darkgreen;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  padding: 3px 10px;
   height: 100%;
  
}
```